# Software which can do batch, planar image stitching

Tags: images, image-processing, stitching

I have a 4-axis motorized microscope that takes images of an insect in a 2D raster pattern, and repeats this multiple times while rotating it. Through software like Microsoft ICE, I stitch the images taken in the raster pattern into a single image, with the idea of then using 50+ of these stitched images to create a 3D model of the insect. For instance, [here are](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OrQ-JKtNvKIEXAAQ6uNnIo6Yh6be_hwv?usp=sharing) 20 stitched images of a stink bug. Each image was created using 35 individual images.

The problem is that I have to run the 2D stitching for each set of images, and this is just too labor intensive for larger datasets. Ideally, I would be able to just select a list of folders and stitch the images contained in each folder --- something like microsoft ICE but with batch capability. I've looked far and wide... does anything come to mind?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying each of these stinkbug images consist of stacks of 35 individual frames?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) which is a very powerful panorama stitching tool suite, (and more). It comes with a GUI but also allows [command line use](https://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_scripting_in_a_nutshell).

In your case I should imagine that the order and field of view values are reasonably predictable so the stitching sequence should be suitable for scripting.

### The GUI

*Sorry no screen shot of the command line usage!*
[image]

Hugin Features

- Price: $0.00 (Free, Gratis)
- Platform: Windows Vista & Later (64 bit current version, 32 bit old version & XP with 2013 version), OS-X, Unix & Linux.
- Open Source GPL
- Multi-lingual *(Brazilian Portuguese, Bulgarian, Catalan, Chinese Simplified, Chinese Traditional, Czech, Dutch, Danish, English, French, German, Hungarian, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Polish, Russian, Slovakian, Slovenian, Spanish, Swedish and Ukranian translations)*.
- HDR Support (Including stacking exposure bracketed shots to produce HDR)
- Focus Stacking (very handy in the macro world)
- Lens Correction
- Automatic Control Point Generation
- *Lots more*

Comment: I puttered around with Hugin but was a bit put off by the required input fields, involving camera lens type and such, which I don't have information on (I'm using a cheap generic USB camera). But given the abilities of it I should probably suck it up and give it a try... Thank you, still open to suggestions on other software that might fit the bill.